# Spark Streaming XML files and converting them to DataFrames

Tags: xml, scala, xml-parsing, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

My objective is to:

1. stream POS log (XML-files) from a Kafka-topic or any other HDFS using Spark
2. convert the streamed data into a Spark DataFrame
3. Analyze and store the resultant Dataframe as a csv.

In order to be sure about what I am doing, I am trying to run it locally for now using the `spark-shell`. The POS Log XML files are being generated using a python script every 1-2 seconds.
The batch interval is set as 15 seconds
`val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(15));`

Setting up the XML stream as : `val xml_stream = ssc.fileStream(PATH);`

How do I efficiently convert the `xml_stream` into a `Spark-DataFrame`?

I came across this [spark-xml](https://mapr.com/blog/apache-spark-packages-xml-json/) package. However, it does not give much idea about using it on a `Dstream` generated from XML files.

I am using `scala` as of now since `pySpark` only supports textFileStream.